# symfony twig extension get config variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig, config

I'm trying to get config variable from custom twig extension.

how can I get someVar from config ?

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('price', array($this, 'priceFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function priceFilter($number, $decimals = 0, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
    {
        $price = number_format($number, $decimals, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
        // HOW TO ACCESS TO CONFIG VARIABLE
        $price = '$'.$price;
        return $price;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

---

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

---

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        someVar: "someValue"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

{{someVar}} is right if you need to read it inside a template

but if you need to get globals INSIDE the extension right there where you placed // HOW TO ACCESS TO CONFIG VARIABLE, then use follow code:

```
/* @var $globals \Twig_Environment */
$globals = $this->container->get('twig');
$vars = $globals->getGlobals();
var_dump($vars['someVar']);
```

Update:
you will need to pass the container inside the extension, so add constructor

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

and pass container at service.yml

```
   twig.extension.name:
        class: App\SomeBundle\Extensions\ClassTwig
        arguments: [@service_container]
        tags:
            - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

Answer (score 2):

You would access it as a normal variable.

```
{{someVar}}
```

See here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

I hope that helps!